# Raspberry Pi Zero W Spikes to 100% Usage Doing Anything

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero

I just bought a Raspberry Pi Zero W today and began setting it up. However, when doing anything, such as opening a window, moving a window, navigating toolbars, etc, the cpu % will often spike to 100% and stay there until I idle.

Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/baf9de6038fcd19e2afa9e131e9da37a

I have it set up with a class 10, 64 gb SD card flash with Rasbian PIXEL. I got the card to be formatted to fat32 using fat32format (http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?guiformat.htm).

(This is on an ethernet connection.) This occurs when using VNC. Using SSH seems alright, but I haven't done much testing with it.

What can I do fix this problem? What other info can I put out about the device?

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem?

Comment: When looking at other videos of people's performance, it seems to be at least mildly responsive, even when using VNC. Is this performace expected?